# What .long 0xXXXXXXXX stands for in asm?

Tags: assembly, arm

At the end of a function, I saw a lot of instructions like below:

```
.long 0xXXXXXXXX    ; unknown opcode
```

What are they stand for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.long` (equal to `.int`) is a directive that tells the assembler to assemble a 32 bit quantity right here. The disassembler typically emits these when data it encounters doesn't look like any known instruction. Typically this is the case when there is a [literal pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_pool), as those don't contain machine code but data, the disassembler prints the data they contain. I believe there is debugging information in the object file that tells the disassembler what parts of the `.text` section is machine code and what parts are literal pools.