# How many Bytes does .fill .long mean in assembly?

Tags: assembly, binaryfiles, data-conversion

i have a script from github https://github.com/akatrevorjay/edid-generator

which is written in assembly, now i want to do some more actions with this Edid Stuff and because i never did assembly im writing it in Python.
For that i need to know how many bytes

1. `.ascii`
2. `.fill  7,2,0x0101`
3. `.long`
4. `.data`

normally have to "convert" it in python.

If it helps here is the full code line for each:

```
start1:         .ascii  "Linux #0"
                .fill   7,2,0x0101      /* Unused */
serial_number:  .long   SERIAL
                .data (Dont have more here)
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C and python?

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation of the assembler? It has the answer for your questions in it. RTFM is usually a good idea when programming in assembly.

Comment: which assembler and assembly language? There's not only one architecture and for one architecture there's not only one language

Comment: @fuz: I actually went looking the other day for another SO question about how big `.long` was.  All the GAS manual has to say is that `.long` is a synonym for `.int`, and that the size depends on the target platform.  Nowhere in [80386 dependent features](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dDependent.html) does it mention the size of `.int` / `.long`, AFAICT.  Of course it's easy to try it and look at output (or put labels and look at the address differences).  Correction: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dFloat.html says `.long` is 32-bit for x86.

Comment: [`.data`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Data.html#index-data-directive) is a synonym for [`.section .data`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Section.html#index-section-directive-_0028ELF-version_0029).  BTW, you can probably put your EDID data into `.section .rodata`, unless you need it in the read-write data segment of your executable.

Comment: @PeterCordes _BTW, you can probably put your EDID data into .section .rodata, unless you need it in the read-write data segment of your executable._ I dont think this is what i want but ill try it. So when im converting all the "bytedata" in my python script i can ignore `.data` because it doesnt write any needed bytes, right?

Comment: @Nico: Right, it's a section directive like `.text`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These ones are simple

- `.long value` puts a long value (4 bytes)
- `.word value` puts a word value (2 bytes)
- `.byte value` puts a byte value (1 byte)
- `.ascii "text"` just puts the bytes of the text without NUL terminator

Example

`.ascii "HELLO"`

is the same as

```
.byte 'H'
.byte 'E'
.byte 'L'
.byte 'L'
.byte 'O'
```

which is the same as

```
.byte 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O'
```

This one is less obvious:

`.fill repeat , size , value`

It will put `repeat times` the value `value` with the size `size`

**Examples**

`.fill 3, 2, 0xab`

is th same as

`.word 0xab, 0xab, 0xab`

`.fill 3, 1, 0xab`

is the same as

`.byte 0xab, 0xab, 0xab`

Complete example:

```
.ascii "HELLO"
.fill 3,2,0xab
.word 5
.long 6
```

this will give you these bytes in memory on a little endian system:

```
'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', 0, 0xab, 0, 0xab, 0, 0xab, 0, 5,   0, 0, 0, 6
|   .ASCII              |  .FILL                   | .WORD |   .LONG  |
```

Comment: First of all, thanks. Am i correct that in my example `.fill   7,2,0x0101` would be the same as .word 0x0101 x 7? So i need 14 Bytes to write `.fill   7,2,0x0101`?

Comment: What is quite hard for me is to get what you mean here beacuse i never did operations with binary data: `.ascii "text" just puts the bytes of the text without NUL terminator`

Comment: @Nico almost. `.fill 7,2,0x0101` will result in 7 times `.word 0x0101`, `.fill 50,1, 0xab` (not ``.fill 50,`.fill 50, 0xab, 1`) will result in 50 times `.byte 0xab`

Comment: @Nico see edited answer for an enhanced explanation of .ASCII

Comment: The added information made it a little clearer. Can i convert `.ascii "HELLO"` to `.byte "H"`, `.byte "E"`, `.byte "L"`, `.byte "L"`, `.byte "O"`? Because i know how to convert int and float in bytes with python but i cant imagine how i would write `.ascii "HELLO"`

Comment: Well, now i saw the added information. Thanks for helping!

Comment: [According to the docs](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Long.html#index-long-directive), "The byte order **and bit size** of the number depends on what kind of target the assembly is for."  IDK if any platforms actually have a .long that's not 32 bits, this question isn't tagged x86 or any specific architecture, so worth mentioning.  (Also the byte-order thing is an issue for arch-independent gas data.)  BTW, the floating-point section [documents that `.long` is 32-bit for x86](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dFloat.html), and the index points to S390 (also 32bit) @Nico

Comment: @PeterCordes I have to confess that i dont know for which target the script above (GitHub) is for so i think ill just take the 32 Bit/4 Byte and see if i can use the EDID Output.

Comment: @Nico: Well, I think on any platform it will be native endian, and a typical size for a C `int`.  That might actually be what you want, depending on how it's used.  (IDK the EDID interface details.)

Comment: @nico `.ascii` does __not__ put a 0 byte after the string.

Comment: @MichaelWalz ok, but when im doing `.byte N` N = Every Char of "HELLO" i dont get the 0 Byte, too, right? So i know what i have to do in python now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Nico you get what you want, there is no implicit 0 byte terminator, period.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Now i saw the line `header:         .byte   0x00,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0x00` this just means: .byte 0x00, .byte 0xff, .byte 0xff ... Something like a for loop? Is this right?

Comment: @Nico yes , exactly. I enhanced the answer to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

What i found out so far is, that `.long X` means 32 Bit - so i can convert it to 4 Byte and get the same result, right?

Found here:
[What .long 0xXXXXXXXX stands for in asm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695058/what-long-0xxxxxxxxx-stands-for-in-asm)

Another thing i saw is that for example `.fill 50,0xAB,1` defines 50 bytes containing 0xAB but what does the "1" mean here?